# Accurately estimating the parameters for mixture of geometric distributions

Tags: sample-size, geometric-distribution, finite-mixture-model

Say we have an i.i.d. sample from a mixture of Geometric distributions:
$$
\begin{cases} 
Geo(p_1) &w.p. \pi_1\\
Geo(p_2) &w.p. 1- \pi_1
\end{cases}
$$
Call the parameter set ${\theta}=(\pi_1,p_1,p_2)$. I'm interested in an estimation procedure with concentration guarantees. Namely, I want the following property: If we estimate $\theta $ using $N$ samples, then the estimation $\hat \theta_N$ we get satisfies $\Pr(|\theta-\hat \theta_N|)<\epsilon(N)$ with probability $\delta(N)$.

Any ideas?

---

My first hope was to develop the maximum likelihood estimator and get the optimal solution:
$$
L(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^2 \pi_j(p_j)^{x_i-1}(1-p_j).
$$
But I couldn't find the closed-form estimates. A more promising approach is to use the EM algorithm for estimation, but I'm clueless about how to show the estimation will be approximately correct. Nevertheless, since this setting seems significantly simpler than GMM, I think it is feasible.

Comment: This 2016 [paper by Chen](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01251.pdf) discusses consistency of the MLE for both parametric and non-parametric mixtures. The EM algorithm is a numerical procedure that returns the MLE, not an estimation procedure per se: its oucome shares the consistency properties of the MLE.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks, I'll take a look. So the question reduces to whether the outcome of the EM procedure is consistent in this case, and what is the convergence rate. Right?